# How can I make Emacs backup every time I save?

Tags: emacs, backup

From time to time I delete files that I shouldn't and worst is files that I've been writing myself. Therefore I have many times been saved by the backup feature of Emacs.

But my problem is that Emacs only makes a backup the very first time you save a buffer. Is there a way to make Emacs do it every time I press C-x C-s?

This is what my .emacs look like currently (only the part that deals with backups):

```
;; ===== Backups =====                                                                    

;; Enable backup files.                                                                   
(setq make-backup-files t)

;; Save all backup file in this directory.                                                
(setq backup-directory-alist (quote ((".*" . "~/.emacs_backups/"))))

;; Always backup by copying (safest, but slowest)                                         
(setq backup-by-copying t)

;; Append .~1~ (and increasing numbers) to end of file when saving backup                 
(setq version-control t)

;; Defining how many old versions of a file to keep (starting from the                    
;; most recent and counting backward                                                      
(setq kept-new-versions 100)
```

Comment: Just found this.. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceBackups

Comment: And this.. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupEachSave

Comment: This solves a problem I never realized I had until I read this question. Cool stuff, thanks :D

Comment: You should put those links as answers dala. They do solve your problem. Also, do you delete your own files so often that you need something like this? If I'm working on source, I usually rely on my version control system to save me from accidental deletions and those happen *very* infrequently.

Comment: @Noufal For me the problem is not caused by deleting the files, but by overwriting them with changes made throughout the same session.

Comment: Your version control should still be able to help. No?

Comment: @Noufal It happens that I make a lot of changes to a file in a short while (say an hour). I don't feel like commiting the file that often.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reading this: [EmacsWiki: Force Backups](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceBackups)

I added these lines to my .emacs:

```
(defun force-backup-of-buffer ()
  (setq buffer-backed-up nil))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook  'force-backup-of-buffer)
```

It utilizes the standard back up/version control but resets the flag that indicates wether or not the buffer has been backed up this session before a save.

First two rows define a function that resets the flag that indicates wether the buffer was backed up during this session.

Last row adds an event hook that executes the function before a save.

This does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Nice. I've just been struggling with this. The docs had me convinced that emacs does this natively but I just couldn't get it to work. This does.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it on your own, here's a start:

```
(defun backup-and-save ()
  (interactive)
  (setq filename (buffer-file-name))
  (write-file (concat filename (format-time-string "_" "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
  (write-file filename)
  )
```

It saves a copy as `originalfilename_timestamp` in connection with a timestamp.

You might of course adjust it to store it in a separate backup folder or add other "tweaks".

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use. It puts backups in a subdirectory of the directory
the file is in. It also saves a backup each time the file is saved.

```
(setq make-backup-files t               ; backup of a file the first time it is saved.
      backup-by-copying t               ; don't clobber symlinks
      version-control t                 ; version numbers for backup files
      delete-old-versions t             ; delete excess backup files silently
      delete-by-moving-to-trash t
      kept-old-versions 6               ; oldest versions to keep when a new numbered
                                        ; backup is made (default: 2)
      kept-new-versions 9               ; newest versions to keep when a new numbered
                                        ; backup is made (default: 2)
      auto-save-default t               ; auto-save every buffer that visits a file
      auto-save-timeout 20              ; number of seconds idle time before auto-save
                                        ; (default: 30)
      auto-save-interval 200            ; number of keystrokes between auto-saves
                                        ; (default: 300)
      )
;; make backup to a designated dir, mirroring the full path

;; backup to dir hung on source dir...

(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'setBackUp)
(defun setBackUp ()
  "Called by before-save-hook to set up backup location"
  (defvar backupdirname "BackUps~")     ; you can chose the sub dir name here
  (if (not (file-exists-p  backupdirname))
      (make-directory  backupdirname t))
  (setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,backupdirname)))
  (setq buffer-backed-up nil)            ; force backup every save
  nil
  )
```